# return dictionary items vba

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

The following line of code returns : `Address`

```
debug.print dict.Item(varKey).Address
```

To display value I was thinking that :

`debug.print dict.Items` would have work but I am getting the following issue :

> Error code 13 : typemismatch

Below is the loop I am using to display the `Address` of the cells which have the same key :

```
For Each varKey In dict.Keys

        Debug.Print varKey & ": " & dict.Item(varKey).Address ' remove in production

Next varKey
```

The data displayed using debugger are just below :

[image]

My Question is what is the way to diplay `Items` and not address ?

Comment: If you mean the *values*, you can't output an array using `Debug.Print` without looping, and since you have multiple areas, or multiple items, you'll need to loop through those too.

Comment: @M.Schalk This doesn't work ^^

Comment: @Rory the debug.print is inside a `For Each` , should I add a loop into it ?

Comment: you want the values? I'm not sure what you mean by items, If the dictionary item is a range the default is the value of that range, just leave the .address part off.

Comment: @Warcupine Yes I want the value, if i delete the .address I still have error code 13

Comment: Each dictionary item is a single cell, or multiple?

Comment: @Warcupine Each dictionnary item are multiple cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this will print each cell value in a range stored in a dictionary.

```
for each key in dict.keys
    printstr = ""
    for each icell in activesheet.range(dict(key).address)
         if printstr = "" then
             printstr =  key & " " & icell
         else
             printstr = printstr & " " & icell
         end if
    next
    debug.print printstr
next
```

Change activesheet to a explicit reference, especially if you are using multiple sheets in your code otherwise there is a chance it will pull the value of the wrong address.

key to get the range, icell to get the individual cell.

**OP 's Solution**

```
For Each varKey In dict.Keys

   For Each icell In ActiveSheet.Range(dict(varKey).Address)
    cpt = cpt + 1
    Dim MyString As String

    MyString = MyString & " " & icell
    If cpt Mod 3 = 0 Then
    Debug.Print varKey, MyString
    MyString = ""

    End If

    Next

 Next varKey
```

Comment: is there a way to not display those data as my screenshot ? 

Example :
KeyName : Item1 , Item2, Item 3 **|**
KeyName1: Item, item ,item **|**
And so on

Your code actually do :
KeyName Item **|**
KeyName Item1 **|**
keyName Item2 **|**
KeyName1 Item **|**
....

Comment: You could concatenate the values together, unfortunately I am not aware of a way to get VBA to print an entire array without iterating through it and printing each separately.

Comment: I will try to join them into a var and the use modulo : each time mod 3 = 0 I got my full string

Comment: @Dorian I just edited in a way to combine them into a string.

Comment: @Warcupine I did it on my Own I will suggest you what I did then accept your answer. Thanks for your time !

Comment: @BigBen Do you know of a better way to do that then have three nested loops? That seems like it might take a while with a lot of data.

Comment: Read it all into an array maybe.

Comment: @BigBen I think you can't see my edit suggestion where I added my code

Comment: @Dorian Works as long as you don't need something other than 3 values in any one item.

Comment: @Warcupine Yep but I need always 3 value as 1 item this is why i used modulo

Comment: Thanks you both for your kind help